# How to access enviroment variables from laravel to react

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have a laravel 5.7 project which uses react for front-end and google maps. I'm trying to access a .env variable to a react component. with this code i  have the following error message :

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError

My api key is working and google map loads if i just set it like key: "edfefefe", but i wanted a safer way to do it...can someone explain me what i'm missing?

PS i have already installed dotenv

```
//my .env file
GOOGLE_MAP_KEY=edfefefe
```

```
//my react component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import './Map.css';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
    let center = {
    lat: 41.083538,
    lng: 23.558191
    }
        return (
            <div className="map-panel">
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY }}
          defaultCenter={center}
          zoom={16}
        >
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must prefix env variables with MIX_ if you want them available on the front end. You definitely don't want the front end reading all of your environmental variables.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#environment-variables

There really isn't any extra safety with this method, it just gives you an easier ability to swap out keys in different environments.

Comment: thanks it worked.
now i have two variables in my .env file!

//my .env file
GOOGLE_MAP_KEY=edfefefe
MIX_GOOGLE_MAP_KEY="${GOOGLE_MAP_KEY}"

Comment: Also by i safer i mean i dont want to push api keys in my github repository..that method seems safer to me.However if you know a better way to do it could you please share it with me?

Comment: Well, Google maps keys have to be made public regardless if you're using their JavaScript API so it's still publicly available anytime you use JavaScript.  JavaScript is a client side language so it's unavoidable if you want to pass API keys on the front end. This method just allows you to switch API keys, not protect them.

Comment: ok but for protection there seems to be in google's documentation a restriction where you can specify a website to use this key and only..i m not sure if i understand it well cause i m very new to all this

Comment: Yes, that would be the proper way to protect client side keys, controlling from the application who can authorize with them

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an invalid key, hence the invalid error from the google maps api

Comment: but my key is working..if i do this : 
bootstrapURLKeys={{ key:  edfefefe}}

Comment: Can you log process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY before return.
Also dotenv works only on server side . You need to add some configuration to webpack to load the env vars

Comment: thanks..log helped me to find the issue..when i log process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY it  returned undefined...